# How to phrase award winning work on CV?

Tags: resume

I was a team member for a Product that won an award where I Product Managed it, is it misleading if I express this as 'award-winning'  or have experience working on award-winning Products?

Thanks

Comment: You can phrase it however you like, but the bottom line is that I don't care very much at all if you worked on an "award-winning" product or not, I care what you personally did.

Comment: Is there evidence in the press or some web sites that your work got this award, and by extension, that you were part of the team? It's not likely they'd care to fact-check it, but just in case.

Comment: Yes, It's an industry award from an independent organisation. The company I work in is a FTSE100 corporate company.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to detail what kind of award that your project won. Both here and in your CV.

If it's an award by an independent organisation, I would feature it prominently (and it would justify the 'award-winning' tagline), talk about how you won it and how you personally contributed to the win. If the award isn't very well-known outside of the industry I'd also talk a little about who hosts it.

If it's an in-company award I would still mention it, but be honest about it and don't pretend it holds much weight outside of the company (aka drop the 'award winning' stuff).

Comment: It's an industry award from an independent organisation.

Comment: @bobo2000 I've updated my answer to provide a few more details on what you can talk about in that case

Answer (score 2):

> is it misleading if I express this as 'award-winning'

If you worked on a product that won an award, then it is not at all misleading to say you worked on an 'award-winning' product.

You should characterize the extent of your work and specify the type of the award.

For example, it's different to say "I wrote an article that won a Pulitzer prize last year." versus "I was one of three editors who spell-checked an article that was the runner up for the 'Nicest Company Blog Article of the Month' last February".

Answer (score 0):

As long as its not a lie.

Did you do a substantial amount of work on the project, or did you come in part way through and happen to be on the team? either way, I would refrain from saying "I have experience working on award winning products" because what does that even mean? How is that any different than working on anything else.

You need to highlight exactly why what you did is important. If you were the lead on this project, then by all means add it, but don't just say "it won an award (whooo)". Instead put what you did to make it an award winning product, what did YOU do to make that happen. Without that information, its really just noise clouding the rest of your CV.

Comment: I was product managing the product, featured prominently but it was a team effort where everybody played an important role.

Comment: As long as you can show you contributed to the fact that it was award winning, you can include it. The fact it was an award winner does not matter on your CV unless your contribution help make it win the award.

Comment: My contribution played a key role to help it win the award (as did others), basically was in charge of the technical delivery of it. The award was given to the project and not individual job roles within the project so not sure how to express this.

Comment: As long as you can objectively quantify it, and explain it. My point is, don't say it won an award, demonstrate the qualities that made that happen. Do use award winner as a tag line